# Group Membership does not include Contacts

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have the business requirement to pull group membership from an Office 365 organisation and resolve all members for each the groups using the Microsoft Graph API.

I can successfully pull the list of groups and drill down through the members of the group however currently the Microsoft Graph API does not return group members which are 'Contacts' - it only returns Users (`Microsoft.Graph.User`) and Groups (`Microsoft.Graph.Group`).

Current Approach:

1. Pull group list using 'List Groups' (`/v1.0/groups`)
2. For each Group returned pull the group membership using 'List Members' (`/v1.0/groups/{id}/members`)

Ideally I need to know whether this is possible using Microsoft Graph or whether another API is available to achieve the business requirement. One approach I have considered is to pull all contacts then evaluate that against the list of groups to work out membership but unfortunately there does not seem to be a call to pull all organisation contacts using Microsoft Graph (there is only a user specific call)

[image: Example Group Membership Image:]
Example JSON (`v1.0/groups/165d8e8d-6ba0-4782-9dbc-251f6f76826d/members`):

```
{
  "@odata.context":"${hidden}",
  "@odata.nextLink":"${hidden}",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "b01eb2fe-1656-4c3e-a1bd-283c057baaac",
      "businessPhones": [
        "${hidden}"
      ],
      "displayName": "${hidden}",
      "givenName": "Richard",
      "jobTitle": null,
      "mail": "${hidden}@${hidden}",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": null,
      "preferredLanguage": "en-NZ",
      "surname": "${hidden}",
      "userPrincipalName": "${hidden}@${hidden}"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "802670e3-02d9-4083-be58-55ab7abef0ab",
      "businessPhones": [],
      "displayName": "Johnny Minty",
      "givenName": "Johnny",
      "jobTitle": null,
      "mail": "johnny.minty@${hidden}",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": null,
      "preferredLanguage": "en",
      "surname": "Minty",
      "userPrincipalName": "johnny.minty@${hidden}"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "6d7a6dba-ddad-4351-b324-d88e575c50e1",
      "businessPhones": [],
      "displayName": "${hidden}",
      "givenName": "Shrey",
      "jobTitle": null,
      "mail": "${hidden}@${hidden}",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": null,
      "preferredLanguage": "en",
      "surname": "${hidden}",
      "userPrincipalName": "${hidden}@${hidden}"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
      "id": "9ad40d3c-ee89-4dd3-a511-a4c16691d695",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "classification": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2017-08-09T07:08:14Z",
      "description": null,
      "displayName": "Large1",
      "groupTypes": [],
      "mail": "large1@${hidden}",
      "mailEnabled": true,
      "mailNickname": "Large1",
      "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
      "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
      "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
      "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
      "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:large1@${hidden}"
      ],
      "renewedDateTime": "2017-08-09T07:08:14Z",
      "securityEnabled": false,
      "visibility": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: By contacts, do you mean guest users that were invited into the group?

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur-MSFT

Yes to clarify a user of type 'Contact' which is a member of the distribution list. If you view the group membership via the Azure Active Directory admin portal then you see 'Contacts' as members and they are listed as 'Other(s)' not 'User(s)'

I need to pull all members for a group that is: all users, all groups and all contacts ensure i have the full membership. (The application being built will be resolving all email addresses for all objects in a given group etc)

Comment: Could you add a screen grab showing what you're seeing in the Portal and the output you're seeing from Microsoft Graph? I'm struggling to replicate this scenario.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I've updated with post with a screenshot and sample JSON response. Note ${hidden} dictates a replacement made to the orignal response in order to keep identifying information out of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group) current only supports Office 365, Dynamic, and Security groups. What you're looking at here is a classic Distribution List (see [Compare groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-groups-758759ad-63ee-4ea9-90a3-39f941897b7d) for details).

The reason you're not getting a complete list is because Microsoft Graph doesn't have a type support for the `Contact` object, it currently only supports `microsoft.graph.user`.

This is coming however. The `/beta` endpoint includes both `microsoft.graph.user` and `microsoft.graph.orgContact` object types. If you try your call against the `/beta` endpoint, you'll find it returns the full list of members.

I do not have an ETA but as soon as [Organization Contacts](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/orgcontact) is released to GA, you should be able to leverage Distribution Lists through the API. Until then, you can do your  development against the `/beta` endpoint. You may have some minor changes to make when it is released but it is unlikely the final version will be substantially different.

Comment: Thanks Mark - to confirm the BETA endpoint returns organisation contacts. I will use this in the meantime then once it hits GA we will be ready to go. 

Thanks for your help.